# ModelState.IsValid alway return false when i try to log in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to login on my website but i have some problems when i do it

This is the login code from controller:

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogIn(Accounts U)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (IsValid(U.Username, U.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(U.Username, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Username or Password");
        }
    }
    else
    {
         var errors = ModelState
            .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
            .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
            .ToArray();
         ModelState.AddModelError("", errors.ToString());
    }

    return View(U);
}
```

And this is the error i get:

> <>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.String,System.Web.Mvc.ModelErrorCollection][]

I also modify the view with one took from internet but still the same result.

PS: Register is working without any problems

**EDIT**

I changed this :

```
var errors = ModelState
                .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
                .ToArray();
```

into this:

```
var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
```

and this is the error:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+d__16`2[System.Web.Mvc.ModelState,System.Web.Mvc.ModelError]

Account model:

```
public partial class Accounts
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [NotMapped]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does the Accounts POCO look like?  Can you provide some data that you are using as well?

Comment: If the Modelstate is invalid, there is no need to copy the errors back to itself. Remove the whole "else" statement.

Comment: We need to see your `Accounts` model

Comment: I assume that you have validation attributes above your properties. ModelState is invalid because some attribut says that valus in that property is not valid. The best way how you can figure out which property it does is run QuickWatch (usually shortcut CTRL+ALT+Q) and write there ModelState. Then you will see list o Keys and list of Values. If you open keys you will see all validated properties. If you open values you will see if there is any error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i resolve thhe probleme.

What i did it was to remove [Required] from EmailAddress from Account Model

Comment: Actually, if you need your e-mail address as mandatory on other places, it should be better to remove "check" validation just in LogIn method. By ModelState.Remove("EmailAddress");